# How to save a word document in given path using Word JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365

I have been using the Word JavaScript API since few month. But so far I couldn't find any way to save the document in given file path through the API. Is it possible to do this using Word JavaScript API?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify a file name or path when saving a document using the JavaScript API for Word (at least not in the current version).

The [`save()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/document#save) method does not take any parameters and the documentation states:

> Saves the document. This will use the Word default file naming convention if the document has not been saved before.

Please note that the JavaScript API is still an API under construction, i.e. there are frequent updates, and more and more functionality is added. You can also get involved, e.g. by voting for request on Uservoice; there are several [request related to saving](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?query=save).